# Write to file in C

Tags: c, input, output

I'm having trouble transferring data from a file to another file using C, and I would like some help from the community to help me troubleshoot some of the output problems. I'm doing this because I want to convert the txt data into binary data next. Totally testing purpose.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
int txt2txt()
{
    FILE *pTextFile, *pBinaryFile;
    char buffer[1000];
    pTextFile = fopen ("AS001.txt","r");
    pBinaryFile = fopen("BS001.txt","w");
    while(fgets(buffer,1000,pTextFile)!=NULL){
    fwrite(buffer,sizeof(int),sizeof(buffer),pBinaryFile);
}
fclose(pTextFile);
fclose(pBinaryFile);
return 0;
}
```

Sample input/output:

AS001.txt:

```
91829812
1231231
1231232
123231123
1232312
123123123
12312312
```

and output BS001.txt:

```
91829812
 „w  O]€©O]    * +  O] ¤O]H¨O] ¬O](     O]   @¨O]Lü( ¾8„w8O]š8„w¥ex      O]ˆ©O]  O]8¤O]          ¤O] ¤O]H¨O]`žO]H     O]    8¤O]œü( ¾8„w8O]š8„wuex      O]@¤O]   ÐªO]Q      ø    H¨O]PO] ¬O]  O]PO]™Qº€O]PO]  D  Q  Q    ¬O]            Q   ˆ       p¨O] ¬O]Õqˆw¹Qºþÿÿÿ|O]
```

Comment: Try changing `pBinaryFile = fopen("BS001.txt","w");` to `pBinaryFile = fopen("BS001.txt","wb");`

Comment: sizeof(int) should be sizeof(char).  I also do not understand what you are doing.  Making a file "binary" mostly means removing text carriage control in most environments.  What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using window 7, and this is just a testing purpose, thanks for all the helps :)

Comment: @BinayakaChakraborty, that won't make any difference.

Comment: ... and `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: @CarlNorum: He/She wanted to convert text data to binary data. The given name doesn't matter, the data would be written to text format if the flag specified is 'w' and not 'wb', as specified in the man pages. This was just at first glance, you already addressed the bigger problem :)

Comment: What does it mean to convert text data to binary data?

Comment: @CarlNorum: AFAIK, text data would have 1 byte for every character in file ( only ASCII, not unicode), while binary data would depend on the type. For example, 123456 as text would would a file size of 6 bytes, whereas 123456 as a binary file would only be 4 byte

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
while(fgets(buffer,1000,pTextFile)!=NULL){
    fwrite(buffer,sizeof(int),sizeof(buffer),pBinaryFile);
}
```

Tries to read 1000 bytes and then writes `1000 * sizeof(int)` bytes per iteration.  Unless your system has 1-byte integers (unlikely), that's probably not what you wanted.

Besides that, `fgets` might not have filled up your entire buffer - it stops at a newline.

Use:

```
while (fgets(buffer, 1000, pTextFile) != NULL)
{
    fwrite(buffer, 1, strlen(buffer), pBinaryFile);
}
```

Edit: Since you're having problems, here's a complete example. First, source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[1000];
    FILE *pTextFile = fopen("AS001.txt","r");
    FILE *pBinaryFile = fopen("BS001.txt","w");

    while (fgets(buffer, 1000, pTextFile) != NULL)
    {
        fwrite(buffer, 1, strlen(buffer), pBinaryFile);
    }

    fclose(pTextFile);
    fclose(pBinaryFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Second, build & run:

```
$ make example
cc     example.c   -o example
$ cat AS001.txt 
91829812
1231231
1231232
123231123
1232312
123123123
12312312

$ ./example 
$ diff AS001.txt BS001.txt 
$
```

Comment: Thanks Carl, but the result is still the same the output is still 91829812 followed by bunch of NULL and weird symbols. When I tried to output it on console, it displayed correctly, but it is acting weird in the text file.

Comment: I doubt it; you must have some other error.  I can provide an example run here if you want.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with my inputs, or do you think it has something to do with my window os font?

Comment: Wait; are you not actually operating on a text file?  If you're doing something different than your question describes, then maybe my answer's not valid. You should probably ask a better (more accurate) question, then, though.

Comment: The program works great if the input is on the same line, however it always follow by lot of symbols and NULL. Or you can say that if the input is separated by a new line, then the gap between the number is filled by symbols and NULL, sorry I sound very noobish. I'm using Notepad++ to open the .txt output.

Comment: int txt2txt()
    {
    FILE *pTextFile, *pBinaryFile;
    char buffer[1000];
    pTextFile = fopen ("AS001.txt","r");
    pBinaryFile = fopen("BS001.txt","w");
    while(fgets(buffer,1000,pTextFile)!=NULL){
        fwrite(buffer,1,sizeof(buffer),pBinaryFile);
    }
    fclose(pTextFile);
    fclose(pBinaryFile);
    return 0;
    }

Comment: int txt2txt();
int main()
{
    txt2txt();
    return 0;
}

Comment: Well, since you're not using the code I show in my answer, it's hardly surprising it doesn't work.  Did you read it?  Particularly the line: "Besides that, fgets might not have filled up your entire buffer - it stops at a newline."

Comment: Thank you very much, the output is exactly what I've been searching for. I will change it little bit to try to convert the output from .txt to .bin. Do you have any suggestion to do it? My plan is to change  pBinaryFile = fopen("WL001.bin","wb"); is that sufficient to do it?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "converting text to binary", so maybe?

Comment: what I mean is to convert the file type from .txt to .bin, and hopefully the decimal data inside the .txt file will convert to binary data automatically. Or does it? Thanks

Comment: No, it won't.  You'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: Thank you for all your helps :) can I add you to my friend list? or is there friend list in the stackoverflow.com?

Answer (score 0):

Include the string.h from the standard library and change your write command to this:

```
fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), strlen(buffer), pBinaryFile);
```

This will stop it from trying to write the junk data in the rest of the buffer, which is undefined.